# Finding an element in a table - selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table where I have several columns but what I'm trying to do is to find the Edit link of a certain entity.
The entities names and the edit links are identified as follows:

```
@FindBy(css = "div#entity_data_manager_table_cell_name")
public List<WebElement> entityNameList;
@FindBy(css = "button#entity_data_manager_table_item_action_edit")
public List<WebElement> entityEditLinkList;
```

what would be the best way to identify the edit link corresponding to a certain entity name?

Comment: Can you post some `html`? The general approach to this type of situation is to use xpath so you can construct it to look for a row item, and essentially go back up the tree to get the row and get the associated edit button that exists in a different column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

You could use a forward axis or an ancestor in an `xpath`. Assuming there is a `tr` that contains your entity and edit button for that entity you could do this:

```
//div[@id='entity_data_manager_table_cell_name'][contains(text(),'some identifying text)]/ancestor::tr//button[@id='entity_data_manager_table_item_action_edit']
```

forward axis version:

```
//tr[descendant::div[@id='entity_data_manager_table_cell_name'][contains(text(),'some identifying text)]]//button[@id='entity_data_manager_table_item_action_edit']
```

This would probably mean you want a dynamic selector, and not a `@FindBy`, so something like this:

```
protected WebElement getEntityEditButtonElement(string entity)
{
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath(/*xpath from above plugging in the identifiable text*/));
}
```

Solution 2:

Find which index the entity you're looking for is in your `entityNameList`, and assuming they match up, use that index in your `entityEditLinkList` to click the correct button. This is a little less precise so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I used the second solution and so far it works for me. Thanks.